# Change android Language to "en" received error "NullPointerException"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

When I start app, I face error, but when I change default language to "fa" (Persian) it works fine. I think problem is inside Values folder. should I change it to Vales-en? the String  inside "Value" is same as String in "Value-fa" I Check it 1000times. But I still know I received `NullPointerException` for `NavDrawerListAdapter.getView.setText` !!!????

```
SharedPreferences language = getSharedPreferences(PRFS, 0);
String langdef = language.getString("selectlan", "en");
Locale myLocale = new Locale(langdef); 
Resources res = getResources(); 
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics(); 
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration(); 
conf.locale = myLocale; 
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
```

Navigation drawer adaptor:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

    imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());        
    txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    // displaying count
    // check whether it set visible or not
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        // hide the counter view
        txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

initiate value  for navigation drawer:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Item_arrey);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array

    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1), true, "Online"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[10], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(10, -1), true, "100%"));

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

Logcat Error

```
 12-10 00:58:43.564: D/AndroidRuntime(9002): --------- beginning of crash
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002): Process: com.sss.exchangecenter, PID: 9002
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at com.sss.exchangecenter.NavDrawerListAdapter.getView(NavigationDrawerFragment.java:385)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1673)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:911)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
12-10 00:58:43.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9002):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: *Vales-en* (without U) is it typo? (btw try values-en, with lower case "v")

Comment: I did that , I doesn't work

Comment: You need a values folder for the default language and check Logcat as maybe you are missing 1 or more words in your translation files. Also probable miss spelled a String name.

Comment: I have values,values-en, values-fa. I checked spelling. 100% sure it's correct.but still nullpointerexeption

Comment: Post the full Logcat error

Comment: Post navDrawerItem and where/how you add values or initialize it

Comment: As i said, you need to post where in the hell you are initializing navDrawerItem, where are you setting it's values.

Comment: Here is the key part. You need to check that the array has the same elements for all the languages and also for the icons (Unless you disable the icons array with a non translatable tag):  navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Item_arrey); 
navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

Comment: thanks Motheus, I can't get this part: "You need to check that the array has the same elements for all the languages ". what do you mean exactly?